# Change the object name to the vertex group name using Python

Tags: python

The script below works for changing the vertex group name to the object name
(g.name = obj.name) but reversing it to (obj.name = g.name) doesn't work?

```
import bpy

#obj = bpy.context.active_object
sel_obj = bpy.context.selected_objects
for obj in sel_obj:
    for g in obj.vertex_groups:
        print(g.name)
        g.name = obj.name
```

I'm very new to python what am I doing wrong?

Comment: One object has probably multiple vert groups. Assigning multiple names in a loop to single object will leave the object be named by the last group. I don't see other reason why `obj.name = g.name` would fail.

Comment: Do you get an error message?